# Как реализовать данный рейтинг звезд?

Tags: html, css

может кто писал, или даже плагин ( но именно с такими звездами, по скругленности)

суть в том, чтобы можно была задать стили заполняемости (например style="50%")  закрасится только половина, 2 с половиной цифры)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну это же совсем элементарно...

```css
.stars{
  color: gold;
  font-size: 5em;
  display: inline-block; /* это чтобы размер блока подстраивался под контент */
}
.stars .inner{ 
  overflow: hidden; /* скрывать всё, что за границей блока */
}
```

```html
<div class="stars"><div class="inner" style="width: 50%">★★★★★</div></div>
```

Можно так

```css
.stars{
  color: gold;
  font-size: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.stars span{
  position: absolute;
}
.stars span::before {
   content: "☆☆☆☆☆";
}
.stars .inner{ 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.stars .inner::before {
  content: "★★★★★";
}
```

```html
<div class="stars"><span></span><div class="inner" style="width: 50%"></div></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но вроде чуть звездочки не такие

Comment: скругления.....

Comment: это что-то вроде символов эмодзи из UTF-8. Они могут различаться в разных шрифтах.

Comment: Вы можете использовать любой шрифт. Можно например font-awesome: [star-solid](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/star?style=solid), [star-regular](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/star?style=regular), [star-half-alt](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/star-half-alt?style=solid), [star-half](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/star-half?style=solid)

Comment: тоесть обычно тут не сильно придираются?)

Comment: @flowers, шрифты на странице вы задаёте сами, через CSS это делается, например, так `{ font-family: "Times New Roman"; }`

Comment: @flowers или вот еще шрифт от [bootstrap](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/) полностью бесплатный с открытым исходным кодом (почти без ограничений в использовании): [star](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/star/), [star-fill](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/star-fill/), [star-half](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/star-half/)

Comment: ок. спасибо огромное